# Converting array of char pointers to void pointer and then converting back

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, initialization

I have to pass an array of tokens to a function which handles thread creation. For that I'm using the fact that the function can take an extra `void *aux` argument.

The function(only the last argument is relevant to my question):

```
tid_t
thread_create (const char *name, int priority,
               thread_func *function, void *aux);
```

I use this array to store pointers to string tokens:

```
 char *argv[];
```

This is how I'm passing the argument(the last one is relevant):

```
 thread_create (file_name, PRI_DEFAULT, start_process, argv);
```

However, when I try to convert back

```
char *argv[] = aux;
```

I'm getting the following message:

```
error: invalid initialiser
```

Is there any way of passing an array of string pointers via a void parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to assign to a variable-length array:

```
char *argv[] = aux; /* wont compile! */
```

Instead, declare the variable as a `char**`:

```
char **argv = aux;
```

Comment: You might like to touch your answer, so I can undo my downvote.

Comment: However, the cast to `char **` isn't necessary.

Comment: Done. I feel it's you who should get the rep since you pointed out the right answer. Thanks for all :)

Comment: @alk if you mean *your* initial proposal of `char *argv[] = {aux}`, you're quite correct that it was wrong. The only thing MBlanc had initially wrong was the unnecessary cast. (his vernacular of a VLA not withstanding, which is something entirely different)

Answer (score 1):

An array decays to a pointer when being passed into a function, so just do:

```
char ** argv = aux;
```

To have a copy of the array referenced by `aux` do the following:

```
char ** ppc = aux;
while (*ppc)
{
  ++ppc;
}

char * argv[ppc - ((char **) aux) + 1] = {NULL};
while (ppc > ((char **) aux)
{
  argv[ppc - ((char **) aux) - 1] = *ppc;
  --ppc;
}
```

This solution above requires VLAs, available form C99 on.

Comment: I find this code too difficult to follow. Why not use `memcpy`?

Comment: Yes, the second loop could be replaced by a simple `memcpy()`. @MBlanc The first however, is necessary to determine the number of elments.